# Optimized ways for defragment mysql database table

Tags: mysql

We have a database in MySQL which has more than 500 GB of data, and currently in the process of purging data and count might go beyond 1 million. As we know that purging might lead to high fragmentation and will degrade performance. Also, under few circumstances where the purge data is more, it may make existing index unusable

In case if somebody has come across such scenario, please let me know best technique to handle the same

Answer (score -1):

No, deletions do not significantly slow down what remains.

No, an index never becomes "unusable".

What are you purging?  "Old data"?  If so, then `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` is an excellent way to purge old data.  `DROP PARTITION` is 'instantaneous' and does cause any fragmentation.  [My blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) goes into the details of how to do the PARTITIONing, and the daily/weekly/whatever maintenance, including sample code.

If you cannot use partitioning in that way, you are stuck with whatever fragmentation happens; `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on a 500GB table would take a loooong time.  (There is an "online" version coming in 5.7, but perhaps not released yet.)

Are you `INSERTing` at the "end" of the table only?  Are you doing no `UPDATEs` or `DELETEs` other than the purging?  If yes to both, then there is a way to optimize the table or to copy the table to a partitioned table...

It involves walking through the table with the `PRIMARY KEY` and copying chunks of rows at a time.

To discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and answer the questions I posed.

Comment: Of course fragmentation can slow down some query that scan table or indexes. When a table or index is fragmented (or bloated whichis a synonym) the number of pages used to do a scan is more important that when there is no fragmentation. This is not important when the query access to indexes by a seek, because the number of steps to arrive at the leaf page of the Btree is a logarithm of the number of pages... One more significant trouble is the place used in memory by a bloated table that through away other table pages that other users would have in memory to answer to their own queries !

Comment: @SQLpro - While valid, your comments are not that significant.  Re the "logarithm"...  In a typical table, you need a 100-fold increase in the number of rows in order to add 1 level to a BTree index.